# Как скрыть блок при наличии сессии?

Tags: php

Вот есть такой код, как его изменить так...чтоб можно было скрыть блок после входа на сайт(упрощенный код)

```
if (! isset($_SESSION['user'])){
//***********************************
$data = $_POST;
if( isset($data['do_signup']))
{
          if ( $_POST['remember'] == '')
          {

          //не актив кнопка
            session_name("user");
          } else {
            session_set_cookie_params(86400*30);
            session_name("user");
          }
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = 444;
}
echo <<<HTML
   <form id="register" action="" method="POST">
     </p><p><strong>Запомнить меня</strong>:</p>
       <input name='remember' type='checkbox' value='1'>
      <p>
        <button type="submit" name="do_signup">войти</button>
        </p>
      </form>
HTML;
//**************************************************
}else{
  echo "ты авторизован";
}

?>
```

Comment: `session_start();` нужно запускать в начале скрипта, а не в конце или в середине.

Comment: В скрипте авторизации она стоит после тк...там выбор времени стоит, а в начале не выйдет...ибо должен быть выполнен код внутри скрипта, а после запуск

Comment: Желательно делать единую точку входа для `POST, GET, PUT, ...`, запросов, а `session_start` запускать в начале работы скрипта в `index.php` с проверкой на ранний запуск  `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE !== session_status() && session_start();`.

Answer (score 0):

Ставите проверку

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    // авторизирован
} else {
    // форма для регистрации
}
```

Comment: <? 
if(isset($_SESSION['user'] && !empty($_SESSION['user']))) {
    echo "ты авторизован";
} else {
    echo "не авторизован";
}
?> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in D:\user\index.php on line 2

Comment: @DfdgDfghgfd со скобками разберись